# String format issue due to new line start

Tags: java, android, string, textview

I have a text String, in this form

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit
, 
lo 
sed diam 
nonummy nibh 
quis 
nostrud exerci.
```

So looks realy bad when I set the text in a textView.

I need that the String is loaded in this form

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing elit, 
lo sed diam nonummy nibh quis 
nostrud exerci.
```

Filling all the row (when is possible) before start new line.

Since cannot edit all the db entries to adjust the text.

Comment: Does your String contain `newline` characters? If so, remove them. Set your TextView to support multi-line text.

Comment: Until and unless your string has `newline`, Text will automatically adjut according to `TextView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to remove all new line special characters in the text

```
yourstring.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "")
```